# Rendering/Displaying null values from java bean

Tags: rythm

If I have a rythm template such as the following,

```
@{
String name = null;
}

Name :  @name
```

I would like to render `null` in the template. Instead, it renders it as a blank string.

Expected : `Name : null`
Actual : `Name :`

Looks like elvis expressions are one way to achieve this

`Name : @(name ?: "null")`

Is there a better way to make Rythm render null when the object value is `null` ?

Answer (score 0):

No, the template engine treat `null` as blank string. If you need to display the literal `null`, stick to your method, i.e. `@(name ?: "null")`